# how to move to the next section in word using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to know how can I move to the section in my document using C#.

I have 3 or more sections in my document. I know how to move one page at a time using:

```
object lineCount = Word.WdUnits.wdLine;

object countPage = 1;

wordApp.Selection.MoveDown(ref lineCount, ref countPage, ref MISSING);
```

I'll try to loop until I found a new section with this:

```
while() //condition to check if found a new section

{

    wordApp.Selection.MoveDown(ref lineCount, ref countPage, ref MISSING);    

}
```

But I don't know what condition should I use.

I hope someone here can help me, I you have better solution please let me know.tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA code it is

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1
```

or even simpler

```
Selection.GoToNext wdGotoSection
```

In C# you could use

```
wordApp.Selection.GoToNext(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToSection);
```

You don't have to create an object for `Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToSection`.

Comment: WordApp.Sections(SectionNumber) also works if you're planning on iterating through all the sections.